# load a returned HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, express

I have a HTML button, upon clicking, it will send a get request to get a HTML file, and I would like to load the got HTML file to replace the current HTML file I have.

The frontend codes look like this:

```
        document.getElementById("single_user_button").onclick = function() {
          $.get('/profile', {token: idToken}, (res) => {
            console.log(res);
          })
        }
```

And I am using an Express router to handle this:

```
router.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/html/main/ll_profile.html"));
});
```

I can see the `ll_profile.html` in the `res` variable. But I have no idea how to load it up to replace the current HTML page. I tried the JQuery `.load()`, but that is for loading into an ID. How should I do this?

Comment: you mean `window.location.href = res` ?

Comment: `.load()` runs on whatever element you selected previously, doesnt need to be identified by an id. For instance `$('body').load('...')` will load the html into the `<body>` element

Comment: instead you can you use .html()